# sharepoint collapse list

Tags: list, multiline-text-field

I am trying to collapse my sharepoint list where I have large text columns, basically following the same code snippert as mentioned here

http://www.bitsofsharepoint.com/ExamplePoint/Site/ListExpandTextField.aspx

and

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14f1b91e-b935-46d3-a95c-cafae852a21a/sharepoint-list-item-row-height?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

but I am having problems getting it to work for SP2013

The code that I add as a CEWP at the top of the list page is as follow

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){
    var jQPath      = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'
document.write('<script src="',jQPath,'"    type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.expandText     {height:auto;}
.collapseText   {height:26px;overflow:hidden}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ExpGroupRenderData(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded) {
alert('Point 1');
    $("#tbod"+groupName+"_").attr("isloaded",isLoaded)
            .html(htmlToRender)
    .show("fast",collapseText("#tbod"+groupName+"_"));
}
function collapseText(group){
alert('Point 2');
if (!group) group = "#MSO_ContentTable";
alert('Point 3');
   var html = "<img alt='collapseText' style='cursor:pointer;' src='https://.../menudark.gif'/>";
alert('Point 4');
    $(group+" td.ms-vb2>div").each(function(i,e){
    alert('point 5');  
           $(e).css({display:"inline-block"});
               alert('point 6');  
                  if (e.clientHeight > 35){
                $(e).toggleClass("collapseText")
             .prepend(html);
        }
    });
    $(group+" img[alt='collapseText']").click(function(event){
                alert('point 7');
        $(event.target).parent().toggleClass("collapseText");
    });
alert('Point 8');
}
$(function() {
alert('point 9');
   collapseText();
alert('point 10');
});
</script>
</html>
```

When displaying the list, the alert trace is as follows:

Point 9
Point 2
Point 3
Point 4
Point 8
Point 10

There seems to be some problem with the code $(group+" td.ms-vb2>div").each(function(i,e){

Has anyone used this code for SP2013?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Jquery to manipulate the view of columns in your SharePoint list, I'll suggest you to use Client Side Rendering (CSR),  it's very powerful and would suit your need. You can write HTML for your need.

```
(function () {
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it output render  
    var linkFieldContext = {};
    linkFieldContext.Templates = {};
    linkFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {        
        "Comments": { "View": CommentRendering}

    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(linkFieldContext);
})();

function CommentRendering(ctx)
{
    var htmlStr = "";
    var itemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var itemTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title
    htmlStr += "<input id='click"+itemId+"' type='button' value='click me'></input>";                    
    return htmlStr;
}
```

This will render your multline text field as button but you can manipulate it to show any html content.

Comment: I have followed the instructions here : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-93e7077d to get some more background, but there is no option to go to List view web-part properties. I can add a webpart, but I don't know if this is the same. I think our site is locked down to much for this option to appear...

Comment: Edit the page, then edit the listview. there you'll see the jslink property

Comment: Yes, I found that property finally. I copied that code in verbatim. It had no effect. Nothing showed in the console either.

Comment: You need to first create a JS file then apply it. Try with a simple rendering first.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. I'll add some alerts in to see if it is going anywhere near the code....

Comment: No trace appeared. So it does not look like either function executes. I also tried the sample as per the MS link above as well, and nothing happens. There is nothing in the Console indicating any problems either.

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be that the JSLINK needs the location to use the tokens, rather than the absolute address... e.g. ~sites, but if I have a site https://oursites/groups/level1/level2/level3/level4/Lists/My%20List/AllItems.aspx then how much of the URL does ~site refer to... arrgghh... more searching...

Comment: managed to get the alerts coming out by trial and error.. gradually removing each part of the URL until it worked. So it is going into the JS now, but just not executing the code... back to testing to find whereabouts...

Comment: Ok, finally managed to get it to work.. the original column I was working with was a one liner, that I changed to be a multi-liner. And I could not get it to work on that one. Perhaps this threw it. Anyway I added a new multiline column and it worked. The alert statements may somehow have messed it up somehow, but the jury is out on this. As it worked out, the example that I was playing with from MS also looked good, so I'm going with that solution too. Thanks everyone for your help. I hope this post helps someone in need.

Comment: Only problem now is that with that sample code you are not able to put a filter on that field....

Comment: Glad I could point to right direction. What type of filtering are you talking about?

Comment: When you go to the headings of each column on the list, normally there is a drop down option that you can select that will filter the column. Once the CSR was applied to that column, the list stated that the filter option was not available on that column...

Comment: I am not sure but i guess filtering never works on multiline column. I can be wrong.