# SP2013 - Adjust Row Height in List

Tags: list-view

I have a multi-text column in a list. The text in the column can get lengthy causing a large gap between entries. I have attempted following the content in this question: [sharepoint collapse list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148639/sharepoint-collapse-list).
However, I could not get the rows to collapse either using the CEWP code or linking the .js file within the jslink property.

I would prefer adjusting the height of the rows, but collapsing the rows is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a CSR override script that will collapse long text fields, and provides a "show more / show less" link on each one that will allow you to expand the collapsed field so you can see the full text if you want (and then re-collapse it).

MultilineShowMoreLess.js

```
var DC = DC || {};

DC.multilineOverride = (function () {
    function renderLessAndMoreDivs(ctx) {
        var summaryLength = 75;
        var fullText = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
        if (fullText.length < summaryLength) {
            return "<div>" + fullText + "</div>";
        }
        var shortText = fullText.slice(0, summaryLength) + "...";
        var fullTextDivId = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name + "_" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "_FullText";
        var shortTextDivId = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name + "_" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "_ShortText";
        var fullTextDiv = "<div id='" + fullTextDivId + "' style='display:none'>" + fullText + "<br/><a href='#' onclick='" + buildShowHideJS(fullTextDivId, shortTextDivId) + "'>Show less</a></div>";
        var shortTextDiv = "<div id='" + shortTextDivId + "'>" + shortText + "<br/><a href='#' onclick='" + buildShowHideJS(shortTextDivId, fullTextDivId) + "'>Show more</a></div>";
        var returnHtml = "<div>" + fullTextDiv + shortTextDiv + "</div>";
        return returnHtml;
    }

    function buildShowHideJS(idToHide, idToShow) {
        var jsString = "document.getElementById(\"" + idToHide + "\").setAttribute(\"style\", \"display:none\");";
        jsString += "document.getElementById(\"" + idToShow + "\").setAttribute(\"style\", \"display:block\");";
        jsString += "return false;";
        return jsString;
    }

    return {
        render: function () {
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
                Templates: {
                    Fields: {
                        "MultilineTextField_1": {
                            View: renderLessAndMoreDivs,
                        },
                        "MultilineTextField_2": {
                            View: renderLessAndMoreDivs,
                        }
                    },
                },
            });
        }
    }
})();
RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~site/SiteAssets/Scripts/MultiLineShowMoreLess.js"), DC.multilineOverride.render);
DC.multilineOverride.render();
```

Things you would need to change:

Obviously you will need to provide the internal names of the fields as they exist in your list.

Also, make sure the URL in the `RegisterModuleInit` line matches where you put the JavaScript file.

And lastly, you can control exactly how much gets shown in the collapsed view by adjusting the `summaryLength` variable to set exactly how many characters you want to see.

---

**NB:** It is designed to work with plain text.  If you are using rich text fields you will probably need to add some code to deal with the HTML you'll get in the line

```
var fullText = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
```

because once you slice that down, you'll probably lose some end tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dylan. I tried applying your code, but it is not working. I then followed a couple of the samples from: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a. I could not get any of the samples I tried to work either. Is there a setting within SP that needs to be enabled?

Comment: Mark, how did you try to apply my script?  Just for the record, where I have `MiltilineTextField_1` you will need to put the **internal** field name of your field.  You then need to upload that whole script in a JS file to somewhere on your site.  Make sure the URL at the bottom of the script reflects the location you plan to upload the file to.  Then, in the list view web part, you need to set the JSLink for the view, also using the URL to where the file is.  And in the JSLink, you also need to use URL tokens (like `~site/` or `~sitecollection/`), not a relative URL (like `/sites/mysite/...`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mention CSS to fix the height of all multi line textbox whether it is in list view or in quick edit view.

```
.ms-rtestate-field {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Change the height & width as per your needs.

Apply this CSS in SharePoint master page if you want to to work for all multiline contents. If yo want it for a single page than add it to CEWP on specific page.

Happy Coding..... :)